# Christopher Pike novel- few teens are the only people left on earth

Tags: story-identification

This is what I remember from the blurb on the back- two teens come back from a vacation or outing and find at first nobody in their hometown, evenutally they 'find the whole world empty' (I think that's how it's phrased). The only other live people they come across are a group of other teens; the only thing all of them have in common is they once knew a girl who wrote dark poetry and eventually committed suicide- the end of the blurb suggests there might have been something supernatural about this girl, questioning whether she was even human.

Comment: Ehm, is it just me, or does this book sound like a completely different book than the one in the duplicate question?

Comment: @MrLister- No, it is not just you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is ***Whisper of Death*, by Christopher Pike**. From [Goodreads](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/137964.Whisper_of_Death) (emphasis mine):

> Roxanne and Pepper are a teenage couple with problems. They leave their small town for a weekend to try and solve them. They don't really succeed, and **when they return home they find their town empty**.
>
> They call other towns.
>
> They find the whole world empty.
>
> But eventually they discover **three other Kids their Age who are still alive in the town.** They cannot imagine why the five of them seem to be the only ones left of the entire human race. They have only one thing in common. They were each directly or indirectly involved in the death of Betty Sue - the plain, shy girl who **committed suicide only a short time ago. Betty Sue - the quiet, brilliant girl who wrote short stories about each of them.** Stories of hate, of revenge, of death in a dead world.
>
> It makes them wonder who Betty Sue really was.
>
> **Or *what* Betty Sue was.**

After a few false starts, I found this by Googling `christopher pike apocalyptic novel teenagers`; the top result was the above Goodreads link.